# TFS common workspace for all the team members

Tags: version-control, tfs

I want to create a common work space for all the team members. As I have a constraint to keep a single working folder only on a sever. I have created a work space and marked it as Public. I want this work space to be accessible for rest of the team members. How do I map it ?

Comment: Whoever has given you that requirement either doesn't understand what they're asking or is using the wrong terminology.  Workspaces are not meant to be actively shared (shared but not concurrently)

Answer (score 0):

Have another user login and refresh their workspace cache from the command line.

tf workspaces /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection

They should then be able to see the shared workspace you created.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I read the question "single working folder only on a sever" that this was a shared workspace on a single server machine so that regardless of who logged into THAT machine they would access files in the same local location.  If you're talking about multiple devs sharing a workspace on their own machines then as the other comments point out, you're missing the point of shared workspaces.  In that case you probably want to clone a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported for multiple users to "use" the same workspace for active development. You need to have a workspace for each user...